# Create a node using services with PHP

Tags: nodes, services

I want to add a new page node using drupal services and REST server.

```
$postdata = http_build_query(array(    
      'type' => 'page',
      'title' => 'aaa',
      'field_test[en][0][value]' => '<p>test</p>\n',
      'field_test[en][0][format]' => 'filtered_html'
      )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-Type: application/json'."\r\n".
                     'Cookie: ' . $sessid."\r\n",                   
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $contents = file_get_contents($main_url."node", false, $context);

    echo json_encode($contents);
```

When I run above code I get an error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://192.168.1.129:80/test/node) 
[function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 
401 Unauthorized: 
Missing required argument node in D:\xampp\htdocs\serv\server.php on line 61
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that you need make an authenticated request, unless you want any user to create nodes. 
I have created nodes before using curl. You need enable the "Session authentication", activate the user login action in the resources section of you service, and enable request "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in the server section.

This is the code

```
    $base_url = 'http://localhost/endpoint';
    $params = http_build_query(array(
       'username' => 'admin',
       'password' => 'qwerty',
    ));
    // set up the request
    $curl = curl_init($base_url . '/user/login.json');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    // make the request
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $user_data = json_decode($response);
    // login successful
    if (isset($user_data->sessid)) {
      $node_params = http_build_query(array(
        'type' => 'page',
        'title' => 'Test page',
      ));
      // set up the authenticated request
      $curl_node = curl_init($base_url . '/node.json');
      curl_setopt($curl_node, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($curl_node, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($curl_node, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $node_params);
      curl_setopt($curl_node, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $user_data->session_name . '=' . $user_data->sessid);
      // make the authenticated request
      $node_response = curl_exec($curl_node);
      curl_close($curl_node);
      var_dump(json_decode($node_response));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

This line:

```
'content' => $postdata
```

I changed by:

```
'content' => $postdata
    'content' => 

    '&node[type]=page'.
    '&node[title]='.$_POST['title'].
    '&node[body][und][0][value]='.$_POST['body'].
    '&node[body][und][0][format]=filtered_html'
```

And now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

This code is worked for me to create new node.

You need to enable "login" action under user section of resources.

```
<?php
  $username = "admin"; //site user
  $password = "admin123"; //site password
  $session;
  $endpoint = "http://localhost/sitename/endpoint/";
  $debug;

 $ch = curl_init($endpoint . 'user/login.json');
 $post_data = array(
  'username' => $username,
  'password' => $password,
 );
$post = http_build_query($post_data, '', '&');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array (
  "Accept: application/json",
  "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
));

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
//Save Session information to be sent as cookie with future calls
$session = $response->session_name . '=' . $response->sessid;
//GET CSRF Token
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost/sitename/services/session/token',
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "$session");

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$error    = curl_error($ch);
$info     = curl_getinfo($ch);

$csrf_token = $response;
$node = array('type'=>'documents','title'=>'tall123');
$post = http_build_query($node, '', '&');
$ch = curl_init($endpoint . 'node/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
array (
  "Accept: application/json",
  "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "Cookie: $session",
  'X-CSRF-Token: ' .$csrf_token
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($response);

?>
```