# Received "An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator" while creating node with taxonomy field via service3 drupal7

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes, services

I am having an error:

> {"form_errors":{"field_category][und":"An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator."}}

Field category is a taxonomy field attached to a node. I'm trying to create a node via web services and unable to create taxonomy field. I have also match post array by doing print_r($obj) on node form validate:

PHP Array:

```
[field_category] => Array(
  [und] => Array(
    [0] => Array(
      [tid] => 6246
    )
  )
)
```

JSON conversion:

```
"field_category": {
  "und": [
    {
      "tid":6246
    }
  ]
}
```

However, in response having an error, the same problem with the other taxonomy field. What I am doing wrong with it.

Comment: I have seen that error when trying to work with tids that don't exist. Have you confirmed the tid in question is in the database?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. After reading [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1354202) I was able to figure out the problem by doing a `dsm($_POST)` on hook_node_update() and inspecting the array and figuring out what it expects.

In my case my array looked like this:

```
'field_term_subtype[und]' => '166',
```

In your case it would be:

```
{
    "title": "your title",
    "type": "page",
    "field_category": {
        "und": 6246
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a node using a POST request.

For the node fields, you can use something like:

```
$node_data = http_build_query(
  array(    
    'type' => 'page',
    'title' => 'This node was created via the API.',
    'field_category[und][0][tid]' => 6246,
  )
);

[...]

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $node_data);

[...]
```

See also: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/72758/7153

Comment: No that is not working, even though I have also change it to 
"field_category":{
                "und":"6243"
            }

But now getting sql violation error

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Json format to create node having taxonomy filed

```
{
    "title": "your title",
    "type": "page",
    "field_category": {
        "und": "termname"
    }
}
```

Comment: getting same error An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator

Comment: Yes it quiet long I wont be able to post it here. In short having an sql error PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]:

Comment: in field_sql_storage.module line: 451

Comment: I have also tried

    {
      "field_category":{
                "und":"6243"
            }
    }

Comment: @MSK I've posted an [answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/106395/25879) to the similar question. That works. I don't know what's going on in your scenario

Comment: @KrishnaMohan - re: "check your logs"  Which logs? Where would a relevant log message be displayed?

Comment: Yes, I know.  @KrishnaMohan.  I was asking YOU, which logs do you suggest he check?